ROS2 removed 'seq' from std_msgs/Header. What is the alternative?
I used 'seq' to prevent darknet_ros processing the same video image multiple times.  Now seq has been removed from std_msgs/Header, I can't do that. Is there an alternative?
To provide context: I have just started using a YOLO package for ROS2.  It works well, but it appears to still suffer from a longstanding problem - the frame rate on live video is around 100 fps, even though my webcam is streaming about 10 fps.  The issue is due to darknet_ros processing the same image around 10 times (the processing is far faster than the camera source!).  This is a complete waste of GPU.  I created a (very hacky) fix for the problem in 2019, which as far as I know has never been improved. It is discussed here. The fix checks 'seq' and only processes images which have a new seq number.  Sadly my fix is useless now that 'seq' has been removed.
I am sure that there are other ways to stop darknet_ros from processing the same image multiple times, however nobody has done this in the 4 years since I created the hacked solution, so I am not holding my breath!

OK, I worked it out - the 'stamp.nanosec' field of the image header can be used to identify images which have not changed.
I don't think this is the right way to do it, but if you want a quick hack to reduce GPU usage from about 55% to 9% (on a Nvidia 1080ti), you can replace darknet_ros_yolov4/darknet_ros/darknet_ros/src/YoloObjectDetector.cpp with:
/*
 * YoloObjectDetector.cpp
 *
 *  Created on: Dec 19, 2016
 *      Author: Marko Bjelonic
 *   Institute: ETH Zurich, Robotic Systems Lab
 */

// yolo object detector
#include "darknet_ros/YoloObjectDetector.hpp"

// Check for xServer
#include <X11/Xlib.h>

//The changes enabled by this switch reduce GPU usage considerably when processing 
//live video (by preventing repeated scanning of the same video frame).
//GPU usage with original code: 51%, 52%, 56%
//GPU usage with switch enabled: 9%, 8%, 6%
#define UNIQUE_FRAMES

#ifdef DARKNET_FILE_PATH
std::string darknetFilePath_ = DARKNET_FILE_PATH;
#else
#error Path of darknet repository is not defined in CMakeLists.txt.
#endif

namespace darknet_ros {

char *cfg;
char *weights;
char *data;
char **detectionNames;

YoloObjectDetector::YoloObjectDetector()
    : Node("darknet_ros"),
      numClasses_(0),
      classLabels_(0),
      rosBoxes_(0),
      rosBoxCounter_(0),
      action_active_(false),
      preempt_requested_(false)
{
  RCLCPP_INFO(get_logger(), "[YoloObjectDetector] Node started.");

  declare_parameter("image_view.enable_opencv", true);
  declare_parameter("image_view.wait_key_delay", 3);
  declare_parameter("image_view.enable_console_output", false);
  declare_parameter("yolo_model.detection_classes.names", std::vector<std::string>(0));

  declare_parameter("yolo_model.threshold.value", 0.3f);
  declare_parameter("yolo_model.weight_file.name", std::string("yolov2-tiny.weights"));
  declare_parameter("weights_path", std::string("/default"));

  declare_parameter("yolo_model.config_file.name", std::string("yolov2-tiny.cfg"));
  declare_parameter("config_path", std::string("/default"));

  declare_parameter("subscribers.camera_reading.topic", std::string("/camera/image_raw"));
  declare_parameter("subscribers.camera_reading.queue_size", 1);
  declare_parameter("publishers.object_detector.topic", std::string("found_object"));
  declare_parameter("publishers.object_detector.queue_size", 1);
  declare_parameter("publishers.object_detector.latch", false);
  declare_parameter("publishers.bounding_boxes.topic", std::string("bounding_boxes"));
  declare_parameter("publishers.bounding_boxes.queue_size", 1);
  declare_parameter("publishers.bounding_boxes.latch", false);
  declare_parameter("publishers.detection_image.topic", std::string("detection_image"));
  declare_parameter("publishers.detection_image.queue_size", 1);
  declare_parameter("publishers.detection_image.latch", true);
  declare_parameter("yolo_model.window_name", std::string("YOLO"));

  declare_parameter("actions.camera_reading.topic", std::string("check_for_objects"));
}

YoloObjectDetector::~YoloObjectDetector()
{
  {
    std::unique_lock<std::shared_mutex> lockNodeStatus(mutexNodeStatus_);
    isNodeRunning_ = false;
  }
  yoloThread_.join();
}

bool YoloObjectDetector::readParameters()
{
  // Load common parameters.
  get_parameter("image_view.enable_opencv", viewImage_);
  get_parameter("image_view.wait_key_delay", waitKeyDelay_);
  get_parameter("image_view.enable_console_output", enableConsoleOutput_);

  get_parameter("yolo_model.window_name", windowName_);

  // Check if Xserver is running on Linux.
  if (XOpenDisplay(NULL)) {
    // Do nothing!
    RCLCPP_INFO(get_logger(), "[YoloObjectDetector] Xserver is running.");
  } else {
    RCLCPP_INFO(get_logger(), "[YoloObjectDetector] Xserver is not running.");
    viewImage_ = false;
  }

  // Set vector sizes.
  get_parameter("yolo_model.detection_classes.names", classLabels_);
  numClasses_ = classLabels_.size();
  rosBoxes_ = std::vector<std::vector<RosBox_> >(numClasses_);
  rosBoxCounter_ = std::vector<int>(numClasses_);

  return true;
}

void YoloObjectDetector::init()
{
  // Read parameters from config file.
  if (!readParameters()) {
    rclcpp::shutdown();
  }


  RCLCPP_INFO(get_logger(), "[YoloObjectDetector] init().");

  // Initialize deep network of darknet.
  std::string weightsPath;
  std::string configPath;
  std::string dataPath;
  std::string configModel;
  std::string weightsModel;

  // Threshold of object detection.
  float thresh;
  get_parameter("yolo_model.threshold.value", thresh);

  // Path to weights file.
  get_parameter("yolo_model.weight_file.name", weightsModel);
  get_parameter("weights_path", weightsPath);
  weightsPath += "/" + weightsModel;
  weights = new char[weightsPath.length() + 1];
  strcpy(weights, weightsPath.c_str());

  // Path to config file.
  get_parameter("yolo_model.config_file.name", configModel);
  get_parameter("config_path", configPath);
  configPath += "/" + configModel;
  cfg = new char[configPath.length() + 1];
  strcpy(cfg, configPath.c_str());

  // Path to data folder.
  dataPath = darknetFilePath_;
  dataPath += "/data";
  data = new char[dataPath.length() + 1];
  strcpy(data, dataPath.c_str());

  // Get classes.
  detectionNames = (char**) realloc((void*) detectionNames, (numClasses_ + 1) * sizeof(char*));
  for (int i = 0; i < numClasses_; i++) {
    detectionNames[i] = new char[classLabels_[i].length() + 1];
    strcpy(detectionNames[i], classLabels_[i].c_str());
  }

  // Load network.
  setupNetwork(cfg, weights, data, thresh, detectionNames, numClasses_,
                0, 0, 1, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0);
  yoloThread_ = std::thread(&YoloObjectDetector::yolo, this);

  // Initialize publisher and subscriber.
  std::string cameraTopicName;
  int cameraQueueSize;
  std::string objectDetectorTopicName;
  int objectDetectorQueueSize;
  bool objectDetectorLatch;
  std::string boundingBoxesTopicName;
  int boundingBoxesQueueSize;
  bool boundingBoxesLatch;
  std::string detectionImageTopicName;
  int detectionImageQueueSize;
  bool detectionImageLatch;

  get_parameter("subscribers.camera_reading.topic", cameraTopicName);
  get_parameter("subscribers.camera_reading.queue_size", cameraQueueSize);
  get_parameter("publishers.object_detector.topic", objectDetectorTopicName);
  get_parameter("publishers.object_detector.queue_size", objectDetectorQueueSize);
  get_parameter("publishers.object_detector.latch", objectDetectorLatch);
  get_parameter("publishers.bounding_boxes.topic", boundingBoxesTopicName);
  get_parameter("publishers.bounding_boxes.queue_size", boundingBoxesQueueSize);
  get_parameter("publishers.bounding_boxes.latch", boundingBoxesLatch);
  get_parameter("publishers.detection_image.topic", detectionImageTopicName);
  get_parameter("publishers.detection_image.queue_size", detectionImageQueueSize);
  get_parameter("publishers.detection_image.latch", detectionImageLatch);

  it_ = std::make_shared<image_transport::ImageTransport>(shared_from_this());
  
  using std::placeholders::_1;
  imageSubscriber_ = it_->subscribe(cameraTopicName, cameraQueueSize,
    std::bind(&YoloObjectDetector::cameraCallback, this, _1));

  rclcpp::QoS object_publisher_qos(objectDetectorQueueSize);
  if (objectDetectorLatch) {
    object_publisher_qos.transient_local();
  }
  objectPublisher_ = this->create_publisher<darknet_ros_msgs::msg::ObjectCount>(
    objectDetectorTopicName, object_publisher_qos);
    
  rclcpp::QoS bounding_boxes_publisher_qos(boundingBoxesQueueSize);
  if (boundingBoxesLatch) {
    bounding_boxes_publisher_qos.transient_local();
  }
  boundingBoxesPublisher_ = this->create_publisher<darknet_ros_msgs::msg::BoundingBoxes>(
      boundingBoxesTopicName, bounding_boxes_publisher_qos);

  rclcpp::QoS detection_image_publisher_qos(detectionImageQueueSize);
  if (detectionImageLatch) {
    detection_image_publisher_qos.transient_local();
  }
  detectionImagePublisher_ = this->create_publisher<sensor_msgs::msg::Image>(
    detectionImageTopicName, detection_image_publisher_qos);

  // Action servers.
  std::string checkForObjectsActionName;
  get_parameter("actions.camera_reading.topic", checkForObjectsActionName);

  using std::placeholders::_2;
  this->checkForObjectsActionServer_ = rclcpp_action::create_server<CheckForObjectsAction>(
    this->get_node_base_interface(),
    this->get_node_clock_interface(),
    this->get_node_logging_interface(),
    this->get_node_waitables_interface(),
    "checkForObjectsActionName",
    std::bind(&YoloObjectDetector::checkForObjectsActionGoalCB, this, _1, _2),
    std::bind(&YoloObjectDetector::checkForObjectsActionPreemptCB, this, _1),
    std::bind(&YoloObjectDetector::checkForObjectsActionAcceptedCB, this, _1));
}

void YoloObjectDetector::cameraCallback(const sensor_msgs::msg::Image::ConstSharedPtr & msg)
{
  RCLCPP_DEBUG(get_logger(), "[YoloObjectDetector] USB image received.");

  cv_bridge::CvImagePtr cam_image;

  try {
    cam_image = cv_bridge::toCvCopy(msg, "bgr8");
  } catch (cv_bridge::Exception& e) {
    RCLCPP_ERROR(get_logger(), "cv_bridge exception: %s", e.what());
    return;
  }

  if (cam_image) {
    {
      std::unique_lock<std::shared_mutex> lockImageCallback(mutexImageCallback_);
      imageHeader_ = msg->header;
      camImageCopy_ = cam_image->image.clone();
    }
    {
      std::unique_lock<std::shared_mutex> lockImageStatus(mutexImageStatus_);
      imageStatus_ = true;
    }
    frameWidth_ = cam_image->image.size().width;
    frameHeight_ = cam_image->image.size().height;
  }
  return;
}

rclcpp_action::GoalResponse YoloObjectDetector::checkForObjectsActionGoalCB(
  const rclcpp_action::GoalUUID & uuid,
  std::shared_ptr<const CheckForObjectsAction::Goal> goal)
{
  RCLCPP_DEBUG(get_logger(), "[YoloObjectDetector] Start check for objects action.");

  auto imageAction = goal->image;

  cv_bridge::CvImagePtr cam_image;

  try {
    cam_image = cv_bridge::toCvCopy(imageAction, "bgr8");
  } catch (cv_bridge::Exception& e) {
    RCLCPP_ERROR(get_logger(), "cv_bridge exception: %s", e.what());
    rclcpp_action::GoalResponse::REJECT;
  }

  if (cam_image) {
    {
      std::unique_lock<std::shared_mutex> lockImageCallback(mutexImageCallback_);
      camImageCopy_ = cam_image->image.clone();
    }
    {
      std::unique_lock<std::shared_mutex> lockImageCallback(mutexActionStatus_);
      actionId_ = goal->id;
    }
    {
      std::unique_lock<std::shared_mutex> lockImageStatus(mutexImageStatus_);
      imageStatus_ = true;
    }
    frameWidth_ = cam_image->image.size().width;
    frameHeight_ = cam_image->image.size().height;
  }
  preempt_requested_ = false;
  return rclcpp_action::GoalResponse::ACCEPT_AND_EXECUTE;
}

rclcpp_action::CancelResponse
YoloObjectDetector::checkForObjectsActionPreemptCB(
  const std::shared_ptr<GoalHandleCheckForObjectsAction> goal_handle)
{
  RCLCPP_DEBUG(get_logger(), "[YoloObjectDetector] Preempt check for objects action.");
  preempt_requested_ = true;
  return rclcpp_action::CancelResponse::ACCEPT;
}

void
YoloObjectDetector::checkForObjectsActionAcceptedCB(
  const std::shared_ptr<GoalHandleCheckForObjectsAction> goal_handle)
{
  RCLCPP_DEBUG(get_logger(), "[YoloObjectDetector] action accepted.");
  action_active_ = true;
  goal_handle_ = goal_handle;
}

bool YoloObjectDetector::isCheckingForObjects() const
{
  return (rclcpp::ok() && action_active_ && !preempt_requested_);
}

bool YoloObjectDetector::publishDetectionImage(const cv::Mat& detectionImage)
{
  if (detectionImagePublisher_->get_subscription_count() < 1)
    return false;
  cv_bridge::CvImage cvImage;
  cvImage.header.stamp = this->now();
  cvImage.header.frame_id = "detection_image";
  cvImage.encoding = "bgr8";
  cvImage.image = detectionImage;
  detectionImagePublisher_->publish(*cvImage.toImageMsg());
  RCLCPP_DEBUG(get_logger(), "Detection image has been published.");
  return true;
}

int YoloObjectDetector::sizeNetwork(network *net)
{
  int i;
  int count = 0;
  for(i = 0; i < net->n; ++i){
    layer l = net->layers[i];
    if(l.type == YOLO || l.type == REGION || l.type == DETECTION){
      count += l.outputs;
    }
  }
  return count;
}

void YoloObjectDetector::rememberNetwork(network *net)
{
  int i;
  int count = 0;
  for(i = 0; i < net->n; ++i){
    layer l = net->layers[i];
    if(l.type == YOLO || l.type == REGION || l.type == DETECTION){
      memcpy(predictions_[demoIndex_] + count, net->layers[i].output, sizeof(float) * l.outputs);
      count += l.outputs;
    }
  }
}

detection *YoloObjectDetector::avgPredictions(network *net, int *nboxes)
{
  int i, j;
  int count = 0;
  fill_cpu(demoTotal_, 0, avg_, 1);
  for(j = 0; j < demoFrame_; ++j){
    axpy_cpu(demoTotal_, 1./demoFrame_, predictions_[j], 1, avg_, 1);
  }
  for(i = 0; i < net->n; ++i){
    layer l = net->layers[i];
    if(l.type == YOLO || l.type == REGION || l.type == DETECTION){
      memcpy(l.output, avg_ + count, sizeof(float) * l.outputs);
      count += l.outputs;
    }
  }
  // detection *dets = get_network_boxes(net, buff_[0].w, buff_[0].h, demoThresh_, demoHier_, 0, 1, nboxes);
  detection *dets = get_network_boxes(net, buff_[0].w, buff_[0].h, demoThresh_, demoHier_, 0, 1, nboxes, 1); // letter box
  return dets;
}

void *YoloObjectDetector::detectInThread()
{
  #ifdef UNIQUE_FRAMES
    static uint32_t prevSeq;
    if (prevSeq==headerBuff_[(buffIndex_ + 2) % 3].stamp.nanosec) {
        return 0;
    }
    prevSeq = headerBuff_[(buffIndex_ + 2) % 3].stamp.nanosec;
  #endif
  
  running_ = 1;
  float nms = .4;
  // mat_cv* show_img = NULL;

  layer l = net_->layers[net_->n - 1];
  float *X = buffLetter_[(buffIndex_ + 2) % 3].data;
  float *prediction = network_predict(*net_, X);

  rememberNetwork(net_);
  detection *dets = 0;
  int nboxes = 0;
  dets = avgPredictions(net_, &nboxes);

  if (nms > 0) do_nms_obj(dets, nboxes, l.classes, nms);

  if (enableConsoleOutput_) {
    printf("\033[2J");
    printf("\033[1;1H");
    printf("\nFPS:%.1f : ( %s )\n",fps_,ss_fps.str().c_str());
    printf("Objects:\n\n");
  }
  image display = buff_[(buffIndex_+2) % 3];
  // draw_detections(display, dets, nboxes, demoThresh_, demoNames_, demoAlphabet_, demoClasses_);
  
  draw_detections_v3(display, dets, nboxes, demoThresh_, demoNames_, demoAlphabet_, demoClasses_, 1);
  // extract the bounding boxes and send them to ROS
  int i, j;
  int count = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < nboxes; ++i) {
    float xmin = dets[i].bbox.x - dets[i].bbox.w / 2.;
    float xmax = dets[i].bbox.x + dets[i].bbox.w / 2.;
    float ymin = dets[i].bbox.y - dets[i].bbox.h / 2.;
    float ymax = dets[i].bbox.y + dets[i].bbox.h / 2.;

    if (xmin < 0)
      xmin = 0;
    if (ymin < 0)
      ymin = 0;
    if (xmax > 1)
      xmax = 1;
    if (ymax > 1)
      ymax = 1;

    // iterate through possible boxes and collect the bounding boxes
    for (j = 0; j < demoClasses_; ++j) {
      if (dets[i].prob[j]) {
        float x_center = (xmin + xmax) / 2;
        float y_center = (ymin + ymax) / 2;
        float BoundingBox_width = xmax - xmin;
        float BoundingBox_height = ymax - ymin;

        // define bounding box
        // BoundingBox must be 1% size of frame (3.2x2.4 pixels)
        if (BoundingBox_width > 0.01 && BoundingBox_height > 0.01) {
          roiBoxes_[count].x = x_center;
          roiBoxes_[count].y = y_center;
          roiBoxes_[count].w = BoundingBox_width;
          roiBoxes_[count].h = BoundingBox_height;
          roiBoxes_[count].Class = j;
          roiBoxes_[count].prob = dets[i].prob[j];
          count++;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  // create array to store found bounding boxes
  // if no object detected, make sure that ROS knows that num = 0
  if (count == 0) {
    roiBoxes_[0].num = 0;
  } else {
    roiBoxes_[0].num = count;
  }

  free_detections(dets, nboxes);
  demoIndex_ = (demoIndex_ + 1) % demoFrame_;
  running_ = 0;
  return 0;
}

void* YoloObjectDetector::fetchInThread() {
  {
    std::shared_lock<std::shared_mutex> lock(mutexImageCallback_);
    CvMatWithHeader_ imageAndHeader = getCvMatWithHeader();
    free_image(buff_[buffIndex_]);
    buff_[buffIndex_] = mat_to_image(imageAndHeader.image);
    headerBuff_[buffIndex_] = imageAndHeader.header;
    buffId_[buffIndex_] = actionId_;
  }
  rgbgr_image(buff_[buffIndex_]);
  letterbox_image_into(buff_[buffIndex_], net_->w, net_->h, buffLetter_[buffIndex_]);
  return 0;
}


float get_pixel_cp(image m, int x, int y, int c)
{
    assert(x < m.w && y < m.h && c < m.c);
    return m.data[c*m.h*m.w + y*m.w + x];
}

int windows = 0;

void* YoloObjectDetector::displayInThread(void* ptr) {
  
  #ifdef UNIQUE_FRAMES
    static uint32_t prevSeq;
    if (prevSeq==headerBuff_[(buffIndex_ + 1)%3].stamp.nanosec) {
        return 0;
    }
    prevSeq = headerBuff_[(buffIndex_ + 1)%3].stamp.nanosec;
  #endif
  
  show_image_cv(buff_[(buffIndex_ + 1) % 3], windowName_.c_str());
  int c = cv::waitKey(waitKeyDelay_);
  if (c != -1) c = c % 256;
  if (c == 27) {
    demoDone_ = 1;
    return 0;
  } else if (c == 82) {
    demoThresh_ += .02;
  } else if (c == 84) {
    demoThresh_ -= .02;
    if (demoThresh_ <= .02) demoThresh_ = .02;
  } else if (c == 83) {
    demoHier_ += .02;
  } else if (c == 81) {
    demoHier_ -= .02;
    if (demoHier_ <= .0) demoHier_ = .0;
  }
  return 0;
}


void *YoloObjectDetector::displayLoop(void *ptr)
{
  while (1) {
    displayInThread(0);
  }
}

void *YoloObjectDetector::detectLoop(void *ptr)
{
  while (1) {
    detectInThread();
  }
}


image **load_alphabet_with_file_cp(char *datafile) {
  int i, j;
  const int nsize = 8;
  image **alphabets = (image**)calloc(nsize, sizeof(image));
  char* labels = "/labels/%d_%d.png";
  char * files = (char *) malloc(1 + strlen(datafile)+ strlen(labels) );
  strcpy(files, datafile);
  strcat(files, labels);
  for(j = 0; j < nsize; ++j){
    alphabets[j] = (image*)calloc(128, sizeof(image));
    for(i = 32; i < 127; ++i){
      char buff[256];
      sprintf(buff, files, i, j);
      alphabets[j][i] = load_image_color(buff, 0, 0);
    }
  }
  return alphabets;
}

void YoloObjectDetector::setupNetwork(char *cfgfile, char *weightfile, char *datafile, float thresh,
                                      char **names, int classes,
                                      int delay, char *prefix, int avg_frames, float hier, int w, int h,
                                      int frames, int fullscreen)
{
  demoPrefix_ = prefix;
  demoDelay_ = delay;
  demoFrame_ = avg_frames;
  image **alphabet = load_alphabet_with_file_cp(datafile);
  demoNames_ = names;
  demoAlphabet_ = alphabet;
  demoClasses_ = classes;
  demoThresh_ = thresh;
  demoHier_ = hier;
  fullScreen_ = fullscreen;
  printf("YOLO V3\n");
  net_ = load_network(cfgfile, weightfile, 0);
  set_batch_network(net_, 1);
}

void YoloObjectDetector::yolo()
{
  static int start_count = 0;
  const auto wait_duration = std::chrono::milliseconds(2000);
  while (!getImageStatus()) {
    printf("Waiting for image.\n");
    if (!isNodeRunning()) {
      return;
    }
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(wait_duration);
  }

  std::thread detect_thread;
  std::thread fetch_thread;

  srand(2222222);

  int i;
  demoTotal_ = sizeNetwork(net_);
  predictions_ = (float **) calloc(demoFrame_, sizeof(float*));
  for (i = 0; i < demoFrame_; ++i){
      predictions_[i] = (float *) calloc(demoTotal_, sizeof(float));
  }
  avg_ = (float *) calloc(demoTotal_, sizeof(float));

  layer l = net_->layers[net_->n - 1];
  roiBoxes_ = (darknet_ros::RosBox_ *) calloc(l.w * l.h * l.n, sizeof(darknet_ros::RosBox_));

  {
    std::shared_lock<std::shared_mutex> lock(mutexImageCallback_);
    CvMatWithHeader_ imageAndHeader = getCvMatWithHeader();
    buff_[0] = mat_to_image(imageAndHeader.image);
    headerBuff_[0] = imageAndHeader.header;
  }
  buff_[1] = copy_image(buff_[0]);
  buff_[2] = copy_image(buff_[0]);
  headerBuff_[1] = headerBuff_[0];
  headerBuff_[2] = headerBuff_[0];
  buffLetter_[0] = letterbox_image(buff_[0], net_->w, net_->h);
  buffLetter_[1] = letterbox_image(buff_[0], net_->w, net_->h);
  buffLetter_[2] = letterbox_image(buff_[0], net_->w, net_->h);
  // buff_[0] = mat_to_image(imageAndHeader.image);
  disp_ = image_to_mat(buff_[0]);

  int count = 0;
  if (!demoPrefix_ && viewImage_) {
    cv::namedWindow(windowName_.c_str(), cv::WINDOW_NORMAL);
    if (fullScreen_) {
      cv::setWindowProperty(windowName_.c_str(), cv::WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN, cv::WINDOW_FULLSCREEN);
    } else {
      cv::moveWindow(windowName_.c_str(), 0, 0);
      cv::resizeWindow(windowName_.c_str(), 640, 480);
    }
  }

  demoTime_ = what_time_is_it_now();

  while (!demoDone_) {
    buffIndex_ = (buffIndex_ + 1) % 3;
    fetch_thread = std::thread(&YoloObjectDetector::fetchInThread, this);
    detect_thread = std::thread(&YoloObjectDetector::detectInThread, this);
    if (!demoPrefix_) {
      
#ifdef UNIQUE_FRAMES
      static uint32_t prevSeq;
      if (prevSeq!=headerBuff_[buffIndex_].stamp.nanosec) {
          fps_ = 1./(what_time_is_it_now() - demoTime_);
          demoTime_ = what_time_is_it_now();
          prevSeq = headerBuff_[buffIndex_].stamp.nanosec;
      }
#else
      fps_ = 1./(what_time_is_it_now() - demoTime_);

      if (start_count > START_COUNT) {
        if (fps_ > max_fps)
          max_fps = fps_;
        else if (fps_ < min_fps)
          min_fps = fps_;
      }
      else
        start_count++;

      ss_fps.str("");
      ss_fps << "MAX:" << max_fps << " MIN:" << min_fps;

      demoTime_ = what_time_is_it_now();
#endif     
      
      if (viewImage_) {
        displayInThread(0);
      } else {
        generate_image_cp(buff_[(buffIndex_ + 1)%3], disp_);
      }
      publishInThread();
    } else {
      char name[256];
      sprintf(name, "%s_%08d", demoPrefix_, count);
      save_image(buff_[(buffIndex_ + 1) % 3], name);
    }
    fetch_thread.join();
    detect_thread.join();
    ++count;
    if (!isNodeRunning()) {
      demoDone_ = true;
    }
  }
}

CvMatWithHeader_ YoloObjectDetector::getCvMatWithHeader() {
  CvMatWithHeader_ header = {.image = camImageCopy_, .header = imageHeader_};
  return header;
}

bool YoloObjectDetector::getImageStatus(void)
{
  std::shared_lock<std::shared_mutex> lock(mutexImageStatus_);
  return imageStatus_;
}

bool YoloObjectDetector::isNodeRunning(void)
{
  std::shared_lock<std::shared_mutex> lock(mutexNodeStatus_);
  return isNodeRunning_;
}

void *YoloObjectDetector::publishInThread()
{
  
  #ifdef UNIQUE_FRAMES
    static uint32_t prevSeq;
    if (prevSeq==headerBuff_[(buffIndex_ + 1)%3].stamp.nanosec) {
        return 0;
    }
    prevSeq = headerBuff_[(buffIndex_ + 1)%3].stamp.nanosec;
  #endif
  
  // Publish image.
  // cv::Mat cvImage = cv::cvarrToMat(ipl_);
  cv::Mat cvImage = disp_;
  if (!publishDetectionImage(cv::Mat(cvImage))) {
    RCLCPP_DEBUG(get_logger(), "Detection image has not been broadcasted.");
  }

  // Publish bounding boxes and detection result.
  int num = roiBoxes_[0].num;
  if (num > 0 && num <= 100) {
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < numClasses_; j++) {
        if (roiBoxes_[i].Class == j) {
          rosBoxes_[j].push_back(roiBoxes_[i]);
          rosBoxCounter_[j]++;
        }
      }
    }

    darknet_ros_msgs::msg::ObjectCount msg;
    msg.header.stamp = this->now();
    msg.header.frame_id = "detection";
    msg.count = num;
    objectPublisher_->publish(msg);

    for (int i = 0; i < numClasses_; i++) {
      if (rosBoxCounter_[i] > 0) {
        darknet_ros_msgs::msg::BoundingBox boundingBox;

        for (int j = 0; j < rosBoxCounter_[i]; j++) {
          int xmin = (rosBoxes_[i][j].x - rosBoxes_[i][j].w / 2) * frameWidth_;
          int ymin = (rosBoxes_[i][j].y - rosBoxes_[i][j].h / 2) * frameHeight_;
          int xmax = (rosBoxes_[i][j].x + rosBoxes_[i][j].w / 2) * frameWidth_;
          int ymax = (rosBoxes_[i][j].y + rosBoxes_[i][j].h / 2) * frameHeight_;

          boundingBox.class_id = classLabels_[i];
          boundingBox.id = i;
          boundingBox.probability = rosBoxes_[i][j].prob;
          boundingBox.xmin = xmin;
          boundingBox.ymin = ymin;
          boundingBox.xmax = xmax;
          boundingBox.ymax = ymax;
          boundingBoxesResults_.bounding_boxes.push_back(boundingBox);
        }
      }
    }
    boundingBoxesResults_.header.stamp = this->now();
    boundingBoxesResults_.header.frame_id = "detection";
    boundingBoxesResults_.image_header = headerBuff_[(buffIndex_ + 1) % 3];
    boundingBoxesPublisher_->publish(boundingBoxesResults_);
  } else {
    darknet_ros_msgs::msg::ObjectCount msg;
    msg.header.stamp = this->now();
    msg.header.frame_id = "detection";
    msg.count = 0;
    objectPublisher_->publish(msg);
  }
  if (isCheckingForObjects()) {
    RCLCPP_DEBUG(get_logger(), "[YoloObjectDetector] check for objects in image.");
    auto result = std::make_shared<CheckForObjectsAction::Result>();

    result->id = buffId_[0];
    result->bounding_boxes = boundingBoxesResults_;
    goal_handle_->succeed(result);
    action_active_ = false;
  }
  boundingBoxesResults_.bounding_boxes.clear();
  for (int i = 0; i < numClasses_; i++) {
    rosBoxes_[i].clear();
    rosBoxCounter_[i] = 0;
  }

  return 0;
}

void YoloObjectDetector::generate_image_cp(image p, cv::Mat& disp) {
  int x, y, k;
  if (p.c == 3) rgbgr_image(p);
  // normalize_image(copy);

  int step = disp.step;
  for (y = 0; y < p.h; ++y) {
    for (x = 0; x < p.w; ++x) {
      for (k = 0; k < p.c; ++k) {
        disp.data[y * step + x * p.c + k] = (unsigned char)(get_pixel_cp(p, x, y, k) * 255);
      }
    }
  }
}

} /* namespace darknet_ros*/


It's great you got it working. If you submitted this as a patch or pull request to the upstream project that's the best way to help make sure it's fixed going forward. People looking at the project are unlikely to find this question here.

@Tully I tried making a pull request, as you suggested, but I am a complete novice using github - I made my first repository only a few days ago.  ChatGPT helped me, but the fix needs to be put in a submodule of the original repository, and I could not work out how to do it (I spent several hours on it).

Yeah, submodules can be tricky. Thanks for trying. As you learn more hopefully it will be easier to contribute. Opening an issue with a good description like above is a great contribution too.
